# Summation of floats in matrix multiplication in in openCL slows down kernel time

Tags: opencl, matrix-multiplication

I have two OpenCL kernels used for matrix multiplication. Both are working fine except for some rounding errors.

The first one is straighforward from the literature. It uses three row-column ordered float-arrays for C = A*B. The given matrices are quadratic, to make sure, there is no side error from wrongly set dimensions.

**Kernel 1 - Matrix Multiplication with floats**

```
kernel void matrixmult(
  global float* a, 
  global float* b, 
  global float* c, 
  const unsigned int rows, const unsigned int cols) 
{

  const unsigned int i = get_global_id(0);
  const unsigned int j = get_global_id(1);
  if ((i >= cols) || (j >= rows)) return;

  float sum = 0.0f;
  for (int k = 0; k < cols; k++) {
    sum += a[j*cols + k]*b[k*cols+i];
  }

  c[j*cols + i] = sum;
}
```

The second OpenCL kernel makes use of float4-arrays and calls the dot product. The matrix B is given as transposition of the original matrix. `float4` is the *interpretation* of the `float`-array defined in JavaCL. So I simply create same array on the host for both of my kernels.

**Kernel 2 - Matrix Multiplication with float4**

```
kernel void matrixmult4(
  global const float4* a, 
  global const float4* bTransposed, 
  global float* c, 
  const unsigned int n) 
{

  const int rowsOut = get_global_size(0); 
  const int colsOut = get_global_size(1); 

  const unsigned int row = get_global_id(0);
  const unsigned int col = get_global_id(1);

  if ((col > colsOut) || (row > rowsOut)) return;

  const int indexA = row*n/4;
  const int indexB = col*n/4;

  float sum = 0.0f;

  for (int k = 0; k < n/4; k++) {
    sum += dot(a[indexA+k], bTransposed[indexB+k]);
  }

  c[row*colsOut + col] = sum;
}
```

My Problem: The first kernel runs 5 times faster (~70ms on a GTX460) than the second kernel (~350ms). The main consumption rises from the summation line

```
    sum += dot(a[indexA+k], bTransposed[indexB+k]);
```

If I use `+` instead of `+=`the second kernel runs the same time like the first, but of course the matrix multiplication is wrong.

Is there a need for synchonized addition of `sum`?  It is used within the same kernel instance, and nowhere else.

**UPDATE** This is the resulting SPIR(?) code (Intel HD 5100)

Sniplet from the kernel with `sum += ...`

```
%32 = load i32* %indexA, align 4, !tbaa !12
%33 = load i32* %k, align 4, !tbaa !12
%34 = add nsw i32 %32, %33
%35 = sext i32 %34 to i64
%36 = load <4 x float> addrspace(1)** %1, align 8, !tbaa !9
%37 = getelementptr inbounds <4 x float> addrspace(1)* %36, i64 %35
%38 = load <4 x float> addrspace(1)* %37, align 16, !tbaa !10
%39 = load i32* %indexB, align 4, !tbaa !12
%40 = load i32* %k, align 4, !tbaa !12
%41 = add nsw i32 %39, %40
%42 = sext i32 %41 to i64
%43 = load <4 x float> addrspace(1)** %2, align 8, !tbaa !9
%44 = getelementptr inbounds <4 x float> addrspace(1)* %43, i64 %42
%45 = load <4 x float> addrspace(1)* %44, align 16, !tbaa !10
%46 = call float @_Z3dotDv4_fS_(<4 x f+loat> %38, <4 x float> %45)
%47 = load float* %sum, align 4, !tbaa !13
%48 = fadd float %47, %46
store float %48, float* %sum, align 4, !tbaa !13
br label %49
```

SPIR code for the simplified `sum =` version only leaves out the lines starting with `%47` and `%48`

Does `fadd`lead to such an overhead??

Comment: How many work items are you running? In the second case you should run 4 times less work items. Since each one of them is operating on more data.

Comment: The work items correspond to the number of elements in the target matrix C. It is a 2D call with nrRows and nrCols. I won't agree, that I only need 1/4 of the kernel calls, but the number of additions (k-loop) in the second kernel is shortened to 1/4. In my opinion the total runtime of the 2nd kernel should reduce to ~25% instead of 500% (less more of course).

Comment: Further comment: the first kernel seems to work only for quadratic matrices, but this should not be a problem for its runtime.

Comment: The GTX460 is scalar device, so using float4 vectors will not result in any speedup. If you save the PTX code that is the compiled output of the OpenCL compiler, you'll see that the dot function is probably just resolving to basic math ops, i.e. it is not hardware-implemented. On the other hand, it should not be any slower either. Looking at the PTX can also give you an idea why it is slower.

Comment: Thanks. That gave me a hint. I also tried it on an Intel HD 5100. The results also differed, but on a higher level (>1000ms).

Comment: I added the SPIR code as update to the question.

Comment: Meanwhile I compiled the programs on a NVidia GTX460 and a Quadro K2000. Both are reducing the dot function to a batch of multiplications and additions. Only the Intel HD5100 uses the function call (see code above).

Comment: In my opinion, SPIR is not a good thing to analyse, when facing performance-related questions. It was designed to resolve compatibility issues. Who knows, how it's compiled into assembler?